Docker python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory script_execution_service exited with code 2
The structure is the following :
├── data_storage_service
│   ├── db
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── initial-db.sqlite
├── docker-compose.yml
└── script_execution_service
    ├── app
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── main.py
    └── requirements.txt  

1)my Dockerfile in data_storage_service is : "

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add sqlite

WORKDIR /db

COPY initial-db.sqlite /db/

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]



the  initial-db.sqlite  is still empty

docker-compose.yml is the following :


version: '3.8'

services:
  data_storage_service:
    build:
      context: ./data_storage_service
    container_name: data_storage_service
    volumes:
      - ./data_storage_service/db:/db
  script_execution_service:
    build:
      context: ./script_execution_service
    container_name: script_execution_service
    depends_on:
      - data_storage_service
    volumes:
      - ./script_execution_service/app:/app
    environment:
      - DB_PATH=/db/initial-db.sqlite


Dockerfile in  script_execution_service :

FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]


And the main.py is the following :

import os
import sqlite3

def fetch_data_from_db(db_path, table_name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def main():
    db_path = os.environ.get('DB_PATH')
    ventes = fetch_data_from_db(db_path, 'ventes')
    print(ventes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

when i execute docker-compose up, I have this error :
script_execution_service  | python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Can someone help me, I am neophyte . Thanks

In your Compose file, you're overwriting the image's /app directory, and all of its code, with a bind mount.  You don't usually want to do this, since it can lead to unpredictable results.
You set the database location to an isolated directory, which is generally a good practice.  When you mount the host directory into the container, you need to make sure you're mounting it into the directory where the data is expected to be.
version: '3.8'
services:
  script_execution_service:
    build: ./script_execution_service
    volumes:
      - ./script_execution_service/db:/db
      #                               ^^^ make this path match DB_PATH below
    environment:
      - DB_PATH=/db/initial-db.sqlite


(Your data_storage_service does nothing at all – its main container process is a no-op tail invocation and the only custom file in the image is overwritten with a mount – and I've removed it from this example.  It's often better to use a separate database container, such as PostgreSQL or MariaDB, to avoid needing to mount anything at all into your application container; this also helps scale the application later.)
